# How to calculate the two original consecutive single-axis rotations for an Euler set

Tags: c++, computer-vision, rotation, rotational-matrices

I'm trying to use some matrix library ([for example](https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Matrix)) to find the roll and then pitch rotations needed for a specific Euler vector.

For example, starting at [0,0,0] (roll, pitch, yaw) then rotating [45,0,0] and then [0,45,0] yields [54.735610,30.000000,35.264390]. With that library it's simply multiplying the two quaternions derived from these two Euler rotations.

When only given [54.735610,30.000000,35.264390] (or corresponding quaternion) - how can I calculate the required roll and pitch rotations? or in other words x and y in [0,x,0] and [y,0,0].

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear, but I'm trying to find the roll-only+pitch-only rotations applied on [0,0,0] to result in that or any other specific attitude.

Comment: You can easily determine a rotation matrix (there are infinitely many ones) that conveys your start vector to your end vector. Once you have that, you can decompose it into Euler angles, for example here: http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=846

Comment: Why do you think there are infinitely many ways of ONLY roll+pitch to get to a specific vector?

Comment: @superware, can you explain how rotating [0,45,0] then [45,0,0] gives a vector rotation of [54.735610,30.000000,35.264390]? I tried it and got a rotation angle of 62.799 deg; your answer appears to have a rotation angle of 71.69 deg. You can work back from the overall rotation matrix to get Euler angles, but you will have to be very precise about which ones you are using, as there a lot of variants.

Comment: Sorry, it was [45,0,0] -> [0,45,0], can you please verify?

Comment: I'm getting [54.735610,30.000000,35.264390] by multiplying quaternions, please see this very simple snippet https://pastebin.com/yWh4ANpJ

Comment: Print your rotation matrix and your quaternion and I'll try to replicate them.

Comment: FWIW, I get inner quaternion=[0.9239,0,0.3827,0], outer quaternion=[0.9239,0.3827,0,0], outer*inner=[0.8536,0.3536,0.3536,0.1464], 
axis vector = [0.6786,0.6786,0.2811], angle = 62.799 deg, 
Matrix = [ [0.7071,0.0000,0.7071], [0.5,0.7071,-0.5], [-0.5,0.7071,0.5] ]

Comment: @superware, I have found your error. You are multiplying your quaternions in the wrong order for the assumptions of the library that you are using. Change it to ```auto attitude = inner * outer;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Tait-Bryan angles (or any other form of Euler angles) there are problems with multiple conventions over axes and order of rotations, whether the transformation is active (relative to fixed axes) or passive (coordinates relative to rotating coordinate axes), whether the rotation is about extrinsic (fixed) or intrinsic (body-fitted) axes. There are also degenerate/multiple-solution cases arising from geometry on a sphere.

The OP's code samples are based on *active* rotations about *intrinsic* axes, but his rotation order is not the more usual one.

**Case 1: yaw about z, followed by pitch about y, followed by roll about x.**

(This is the more usual case, at least in flight, but it is not what the OP is using.)

Thinking first about the corresponding passive transformations (change of coordinate axes) and then transposing back to get the active transformations, the rotation matrix R is

(X<sup>T</sup>Y<sup>T</sup>Z<sup>T</sup>)<sup>T</sup>=Z(z)Y(y)X(x)

which works out as https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbnSh.png
from which you can - in *most* cases - pick off the original Tait-Bryan angles:

```
roll(x)=atan2(R32,R33)
pitch(y)=asin⁡(-R31)
yaw(z)=atan2(R21,R11)
```

(The matrix indices R11, R12 etc. are 1-based here.)

The exception is when cos(y)=0 - gimbal lock - when roll and yaw must be picked off (non-uniquely) from the other terms in the matrix. Of course, at this point the pitch angle will be plus or minus 90 degrees and the passengers in the aircraft will be a little unhappy with the pilot.

**Case 2: roll about x, followed by pitch about y, followed by yaw about z.**

(This is actually what the OP is using (from his code snippet), but it is not the more common case.)

(Z<sup>T</sup>Y<sup>T</sup>X<sup>T</sup>)<sup>T</sup>=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)

The rotation matrix R is given by
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLN21.png
from which you can - again, in *most* cases - pick off the Tait-Bryan angles:

```
roll(x)=atan2(-R23,R33)
pitch(y)=asin(R13)
yaw(z)=atan2(-R12,R11)
```

If the order of rotations is different then you will have to adapt your matrix and formulae accordingly.

Some useful things about rotation matrices:

1. The rows (and columns) are orthonormal.
2. The inverse matrix is the transposed matrix (and is also the way of switching from active to passive transformations).
3. The determinant is +1 (if it is -1 then you've walked through a mirror!)
4. The columns of the active rotation matrix are the mapping of the original unit vectors [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]. (Actually, that is
   true of any matrix transformation, regardless of whether it is a
   rotation or not.)

Personally, I don't use Euler angles or quaternions much. I would usually deal either with the rotation matrix or the mappings of the unit vectors (which form the columns of the rotation matrix, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Word of advice: avoid using Euler angles in your code like the plague. IMHO the only place where Euler angles have use is in sending control commands to a physical actuator that actually changes roll, pitch or yaw, or when receiving data from a sensor that directly measures them (or, more likely, their time derivatives, i.e. gyros). And the only thing one should do with such data is "immediately" convert them to or from another representation that can un-ambiguosly be understood and debugged by a human. Euler angles are not that: their deceptive simplicity/intuitiveness hides monsters (gimbal lock, order ambiguity, non-trivial interpolation, to name a few) that cause trouble all.the.time.

Use rotation (3x3) or roto-translation (4x4) matrices where speed or accuracy is not an issue, or in the places where you need to log (or "see") your state, and quaternions everywhere else. Converting between quaternions and matrices is trivial, and there are plenty of libraries to help you do that. Interpreting the columns of rotation matrices as the unit vectors of coordinate frames is how you understand and debug kinematics problems.

Apologies if the above sounds opinionated, I have spent a little too many hours debugging other people's broken code using Euler angles, and coaching more junior engineers on why they are best avoided. War stories available on request :-)